# Excel fails to open Python-generated CSV files

Tags: python, excel, csv, osx-mavericks

I have many Python scripts that output CSV files. It is occasionally convenient to open these files in Excel. After installing OS X Mavericks, Excel no longer opens these files properly: Excel doesn't parse the files and it duplicates the rows of the file until it runs out of memory. Specifically, when Excel attempts to open the file, a prompt appears that reads: "File not loaded completely."

Example of code I'm using to generate the CSV files:

```
import csv
with open('csv_test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([1,2,3])
    writer.writerow([4,5,6])
```

Even the simple file generated by the above code fails to load in Excel. However, if I open the CSV file in a text editor and copy/paste the text into Excel, parse it with text to columns, and then save as CSV from Excel, then I can reopen the CSV file in Excel without issue. Do I need to pass an additional parameter in my scripts to make Excel parse the CSV files the same way it used to? Or is there some setting I can change in OS X Mavericks or Excel? Thanks.

Comment: Definitely not a python problem. As for how to use excel, ask on SuperUser...

Comment: To confirm: The code above (when properly indented of course) creates a CSV file that Excel is unable to read?

Comment: Excel for Mac, or Excel on Windows?

Comment: I have similar scripts but only use open(filename, 'w') rather than passing the b flag also. Give that a try? I can't replicate your issue either way though.

Comment: This works perfectly on OSX ML, python 2.7.2, excel 2011.

Comment: I'm getting the same error in Excel for Mac 2011 (14.3.8) opening CSVs generated using PHP 5.3.27's fputcsv() function on a CentOS box.  The same files opened fine before I installed Mavericks. So this probably is a problem with Excel's CSV import under Mavericks.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I had the similar problem, the error message "SYLK: File format is not valid" when open python autogenerated csv file. The solution is really funny. The first two characters must not be `I` and `D` in uppercase (`ID`). Also see ["SYLK: File format is not valid" error message when you open file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323626).

Comment: You were right! this is hilarious and sad at the same time

Comment: lol, it works. I was 99% sure something like this will not work ;)
Microsoft link dead btw

Comment: The Microsoft KB link is indeed dead—even the Internet Archive Wayback Machine can't find it. However Wikipedia has some interesting information about their proprietary [Symbolic Link (SYLK)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_Link_(SYLK)) file format and CSV files.

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution1: use *.txt instead of *.csv. In this case Excel (at least, 2010) will show you an import data wizard where you can specify delimiters, character encoding, field types, etc.

UPD: Solution2:
The python "csv" module has a "dialect" feature. For example, the following modification of your code generates valid csv file for my environment (Python 2.7, Excel 2010, Windows7, locale with ";" list delimiters):

```
import csv
with open('csv_test2.csv', 'wb') as f:
    csv.excel.delimiter=';'
    writer = csv.writer(f, dialect=csv.excel)
    writer.writerow([1,2,3])
    writer.writerow([4,5,6])
```