# opening text files in different folders and write to a csv cell

Tags: python, csv, glob

I am trying to get texts from different folders and write each text into a single cell in a CSV format with its file name (*.txt)

```
import os
folders = os.listdir("/Users/hilo/Documents/digitization/ReleasedDataset_mp3")
folders

import  glob, csv
```

here I tried to get the list of folder names, and they are like:

```
['Becton Dickinson_20170803',
 'CIGNA Corp._20170202',
 'The Bank of New York Mellon Corp._20170720',
 'JPMorgan Chase & Co._20170714']
```

here I try to apply a loop to open and extract all text from each *txt file and write all text into a cell in the csv file with the key( *)

```
for i in folders:
    files=glob.glob("/Users/hilo/Documents/digitization/ReleasedDataset_mp3/i/*.txt")
with open('writeData.csv', mode='w') as new_file:
  writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
  for filename in files:

    # Take all sentences from a given file
    file = open(filename, 'rt')
    text = file.read()
    file.close()

    for text in text:
      writer.writerow((filename, text))
```

this keeps producing an empty CSV. does anyone have a suggestion to solve the issue in the code?

Comment: Are you sure the `for filename in files:` is producing the filenames you want? Also, when you `open()` the output CSV file, include an `newline=""` keyword argument since the text in a single cell may include newline characters.

Comment: @martineau you are right, the filename in files comment does not producing the filenames, I just tried it. I think that's the bug I have :) I am trying to understand where does it fail cause the path is correct, I also improved it with interpolation with tbhaxor's comment.  do you have any suggestion?

Comment: It's unclear to me what the file hierarchy is. What is the root folder which is the parent of all the subfolders? Are all the subfolders directly beneath it or are they nested further down?

Comment: @martineau many thanks for your comment :)
 path: /Users/hilo/Documents/digitization/ReleasedDataset_mp3/ i / *.txt meaning that each i folder has a txt file and other files inside. from folders in i, we are trying to get only *.txt files. as a side note, I was reading your comments on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520040/csv-writer-writing-all-contents-to-one-cell and it helped me a lot to shape the current version :)

Comment: OK, that enough information for me to provide an answer (see below). Yes, writing raw text into a CSV cell can indeed be problematic, as illustrated by the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work, based on the additional information you provided in the comments:

```
import csv
import glob
import os
from pprint import pprint, pp


#root_folder = "/Users/hilo/Documents/digitization/ReleasedDataset_mp3"
root_folder = "/Stack Overflow/_test_files_root"

#folders = ['Becton Dickinson_20170803',
#           'CIGNA Corp._20170202',
#           'The Bank of New York Mellon Corp._20170720',
#           'JPMorgan Chase & Co._20170714']
folders = ['Subfolder1', 'Subfolder3']

filepaths = []
for subfolder in folders:
    filepaths.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(root_folder, subfolder, "*.txt")))

if os.name == 'nt':  # Improve readability on Windows (optional)
    filepaths[:] = [filepath.replace('\\', '/') for filepath in filepaths]
pprint(filepaths, width=128)  # Show files to be processed (optional)

# Process the files.
with open('writeData.csv', mode='w', newline='') as new_file:
    writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for filename in filepaths:
        # Take all sentences from a given file.
        with open(filename, 'rt') as file:
            text = file.read()
        # Write them into CSV along with filename.
        writer.writerow((filename, text))

print('-FINI-')
```

Here's what the file created looks like in Excel:
(I used text from various online news articles for testing.)

[image: screenshot of file in Excel]

Comment: thank you for your help and code suggestion, I am super excited. just a quick question, I am trying to push each .txt file into one cell. such that, each cell will have one entire text file.  i think with this code, each letter goes into one cell with these writerow function. I tried with writerows too, but it got worse :). @martineau

Comment: No, `writerow()` is the right method. The code creates a separate row in the CSV for each file. Each of the rows of the output file consists of two cells, the first is the filename and the other is the contents of that file. The two cells are delimited with a comma. The file contents cell has quotes surrounding the text in it. This is exactly what I expected (and thought you wanted).

Comment: thank you so much for the code and all these amazing guidances. 
 I think the issue is related to , vs : separation. as you also point here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520040/csv-writer-writing-all-contents-to-one-cell

the issue is the csv file looks amazing when I open at python but the text is everywhere when  I open with excel (csv).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean about "related to , vs : separation". The CSV `delimiter` is being set to `','` and the `csv` module will properly handle those characters being embedded in file content (as should Excel). Again my own results are not the same as yours, because things looked fine when I opened the CSV that gets created in Excel 2013. Perhaps it has something to do with your data (or the regional settings on your computer). See if you can provide a [mre] — which in this case means providing some sample file content that it doesn't work with properly.

Comment: hI @martineau many thanks for all your support and help. I attached a small sample of data through google drive, and I hope this is in line with StackOverflow rules. the data is from earning call disclosures of US based public companies. int he folders there are audio files too, which I try to ignore by only extracting content from txt documents and writing into one cell. and the issue is  it looks great at python but once you open on with excel, it looks corrupted and text is in almost in all columns.

Comment: I think the issue is related to dialect vs delimiting issue due to excel. I tried to overcome this by setting dialect = excel. but did not work either.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611160/excel-fails-to-open-python-generated-csv-files

Comment: Your "small" sample of data is 32.8MB! when zipped, mostly because of all those non-text audio files which are completely unnecessary. Even the text files are huge being in the 22-32KB range each. All that is needed are a few small text files in different folders since ignoring non-text files is not part of the problem. Minimal means contain just enough text to reproduce the problem. Figuring that out and creating a set of test files will likely require some work on your part. Note I did something like that on my own to test the code in my answer.

Comment: Hilal: Sorry to say I'm not going to work on this issue of writing the data to the CSV file anymore. From my perspective I have already answered your original question with respect to accessing the files in the various folders goes. However doing that has revealed a separate problem having to do with the *processing* of the data in those file and getting it into the CSV file properly. For that you need to ask a new question. Please do so and let me know. In the new question, also note what your computer's regional settings are set to (i.e. Turkey/Turkish).

Comment: you are definitely right, I really enjoyed the debate here, you are an amazing expert. thousands of thanks for all your kind replies and guidance. we have a lot to learn from you :)  have a great week.

Comment: You are welcome — glad I was able to at least partially help. Thanks for the compliments and good luck with your project. BTW, it occurred to me that the issue might be the size of those text files, trying to stuff that much data into a single cell may be exceeding Excel's limits. You could easily test this speculation.

Comment: I tested that yesterday and I think that might be one of the causes. almost 32k is the max limit for that. so 1. excel single cell limit, 2. zip|unzip process, 3. excel- dialect issue :) as a side note, I understood the issue when you said it is OK with excel 2013, so I  I run the code on google colab and save it as csv, and without opening the csv file, I imported back to process some NLP algorithms. and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the string interpolation in 2nd line.

It should be `files=glob.glob(f"/Users/hilo/Documents/digitization/ReleasedDataset_mp3/{i}/*.txt")`

Now it will replace the value of i from the loop, instead of interpreting it as a literal value

Comment: hi @tbhaxor, thanks for your answer. we are so close to solving the issue. I tried your answer but it also produces an empty csv file.

Comment: tbhaxor: Good suggestion, but unfortunately it ignores the fact that the assignment is being done *multiple* times in a `for`-loop, so only the files from the *last* iteration of the loop will end up in `files`.

Comment: that explains why only the last file in the last subfolder is being processed. Martineau, you are an amazing coder!